# Why .NET Core loads dependencies that have superior version?

Tags: .net, .net-core, nuget, clr, coreclr

I have a project that depends on Newtonsoft.Json v12.0.1, when i delete this version from the bin folder and i put superior versions (e.g. v13.0.1) the app keeps executing normally.

My questions are :

Why the CoreCLR loads dependencies superior of the one specified in assembly ?

Doesn't the CoreCLR applies [version policy like CLR in .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/how-the-runtime-locates-assemblies)?

Is even the CoreCLR responsible for resolving dependencies at runtime?

I saw this two documents on resolution of dependencies but they don't clarify the version resolution point.

https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/v2.0.0/Documentation/specs/corehost.md https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dependency-loading/default-probing

Comment: Maybe [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning#version-ranges) can help a little bit?

Comment: @GuruStron thank you, it's a part of the answer but i am still confused how this is resolved at runtime, assembly manifest specifies only one version still wondering about the logic behind loading superior version at runtime.

Comment: Relevent documentation [is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library-guidance/versioning).  Quoting: "In .NET Core, assembly loading is more relaxed. The .NET Core runtime automatically loads assemblies with a higher version at run time."

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks a lot, that's what i was looking for.